# Unable to scrape the link from DuckDuckGo search result

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape the 1st link from DuckDuckGo search result . I wrote the below code :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
class Bse:
      def currentPrice(self,symbol):
            headers = {
                  "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:84.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/84.0"
            }
            duckDuckUrl=f'https://duckduckgo.com/?q=bse+{symbol}+stock+price'
            response=requests.get(duckDuckUrl,headers=headers)
            soup=BeautifulSoup(response.text,"html.parser")
             bseIndiaLink=soup.find_all('a')
            # bseIndiaLink=soup.find_all('a',class_="result__a")  #giving empty list
            print(bseIndiaLink)


bse=Bse()
bse.currentPrice('reliance')
```

Firstly I used find_all() in beautifulSoup without class_ argument . It returned me a list of some random anchor tags that is not of any use to me .
I also tried find_all() with class_ argument but then it returned me an empty list.

I tried to print soup object . It print's the web page's HTML but not those result containing divs. I don't know why BeautifulSoup is not scraping the result containing divs. Please look at the screenshot , the highlighted HTML syntax is what I want to scrape :
[image]

I found an answer that DuckDuckGo uses javascript for it search results and beautifulSoup can't scrape javascript , but on the other posts on StackOverflow I found that people are able to scrape the link from it results .
But if I use Google instead of DuckDuckGo , I am able to scrape the required link .

I want to know why I am not able to scrape from DuckDuckGo ,but instead from Google using the same code . I am curious about it.

If anyone knows what I am overlooking or missing , please let me know . It will help me in my learning journey .

Thank You

Comment: Try this URL https://html.duckduckgo.com/html/?q=nse%20reliance%20stock%20price

Comment: @artanik itls showing me this error :- requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Invalid URL 'html.duckduckgo.com/html/?q=nse%20reliance%20stock%20price': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http://html.duckduckgo.com/html/?q=nse%20reliance%20stock%20price?

Answer (score 2):

This should produce results based on your current search keyword. You need to send post http requests along with appropriate parameters to reach the content. I've used some string formatting within payload in order for your current attempt to be successful.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

class Bse:
    def __init__(self):
        self.duckDuckUrl = 'https://html.duckduckgo.com/html/'
        self.payload = {'q': 'bse {} stock price','b': ''}
        self.headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:84.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/84.0'}

    def currentPrice(self,symbol):
        self.payload['q'] = self.payload['q'].format(symbol)
        res = requests.post(self.duckDuckUrl,data=self.payload,headers=self.headers)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,'html.parser')
        return soup.find('a',class_='result__a').get("href")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    bse = Bse()
    print(bse.currentPrice('reliance'))
```

Using get requests:

```
link = "https://html.duckduckgo.com/html/?"
params = {'q': 'nse {} stock price'}

def fetch_first_link(s,symbol):
    params['q'] = params['q'].format(symbol)
    res = s.get(link,params=params)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
    item = soup.select_one(".result__title > a.result__a").get("href")
    return item

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with requests.Session() as s:
        s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36'
        print(fetch_first_link(s,'reliance'))
```

Comment: It's working now . But why you have used post request why isn't get request ?

Answer (score 0):

> Firstly I used find_all() in beautifulSoup without class_ argument. It returned me a list of some random anchor tags that are not of any use to me.

It is correct behavior since you asked `bs4` to get all `<a>` tags and it returned all `<a>` tags that were found.

You can change your URL to scrape non-JavaScript version:

```
from this (JS): https://duckduckgo.com/?q=bse+reliance+stock+price&t=hx&va=g&ia=web
to this (non-JS): https://html.duckduckgo.com/html/?q=bse%20reliance%20stock%20price
```

If you need to extract only **first** link each time, then you can do like this:

```py
>>> first_url = soup.select_one('.result__url')['href'].replace('//', '')
"duckduckgo.com/l/?uddg=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.bseindia.com%2Fstock%2Dshare%2Dprice%2Freliance%2Dindustries%2Dltd%2Freliance%2F500325%2F&rut=b13b3c373de61ffd03dee7ad51f9fb9274dac16d098f25920d7946dbd9a73cc7"
```

Code and [full example in the online IDE](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/Scrape-DuckDuckGo-Non-JS-verison#main.py):

```py
import requests, lxml
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    'User-agent':
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}

params = {
  "q": "bse reliance stock price",
  "kl": "us-en" # language
}

html = requests.get('https://html.duckduckgo.com/html', headers=headers, params=params)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'lxml')

first_url = soup.select_one('.result__url')['href'].replace('//', '')
print(first_url)

# duckduckgo.com/l/?uddg=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.bseindia.com%2Fstock%2Dshare%2Dprice%2Freliance%2Dindustries%2Dltd%2Freliance%2F500325%2F&rut=b13b3c373de61ffd03dee7ad51f9fb9274dac16d098f25920d7946dbd9a73cc7
```

---

Alternatively, you can use [DuckDuckGo Organic Results API](https://serpapi.com/duckduckgo-organic-results) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free plan. Check out the [playground](https://serpapi.com/playground?engine=duckduckgo&q=Coffee&kl=us-en).

The difference is that it scrapes the JavaScript version of DuckDuckGo and the only thing that needs to be done is just to iterate over JSON string and extract what you're looking for.

Code to integrate:

```py
from serpapi import GoogleSearch
import os

params = {
  "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"),
  "engine": "duckduckgo",
  "q": "bse reliance stock price",
  "kl": "us-en"
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()

# [0] - index of the first organic result
first_link = results['organic_results'][0]['link']
print(first_link)

# https://www.bseindia.com/stock-share-price/reliance-industries-ltd/reliance/500325/
```

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.